# okhttp3 как вернуть результат в UI поток?

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток.

Через okhttp3 делаю асинхронный запрос:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            String jsonData = response.body().string();

            try {
                JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                String id = jobject.getString("id");

                //increment current id +1
                String last_id = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(id)+1);
                Log.i("new id", last_id);
                if(response!=null){
                    response.getJsonResponse(last_id)
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Log.i("ok", response.body().string());
        }
    });
```

Интерфейс для callback:

```
public interface getResponse {
         void getJsonResponse(final String id);    
    }
```

И собственно запуск запроса из Activity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Helper helper = new Helper();
      helper.getLastId(new getResponse(){
            @Override
            void getJsonResponse(String id){

            }
    });
}}
    }
```

Вот не могу понять как в getJsonResponse получить объект Activity, из которой делал запрос (нужно например, изменить произвольный TextView).

Пробовал уже прокидывать this в вызове helper.getLastId() и по всем callback, но всё равно не получается, хотя в отладчике видно, что в getJsonResponse() приходит правильный Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как метод `getResponse().getJsonResponse(String id)` выполняется НЕ в основном потоке, потому что вызывается в потоке, выполняющем запрос, вы не можете в этом методе напрямую обращаться к элементам пользовательского интерфейса. Получите ошибку, что к элементам пользовательского интерфейса можно обращаться только из потока, в котором они созданы, а именно из основного потока.

Есть разные способы реализации.

В вашем случае, с минимальными изменениями в коде, в принципе, можно сделать как-то так с использованием `Handler`

```
    public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

     private Handler handler;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());

       Helper helper = new Helper();
       helper.getLastId(new getResponse(){
           @Override
           void getJsonResponse(String id){
               handler.post(
                   new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           HomeActivity.this.textView.setText(id);
                       }
                   });

           }
       );
     }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Тогда проще вообще сделать `Handler` + обычный, не асинхронный запрос `okhttp3`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запустить через HomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
 //объявляем TextView
 TextView tv_text;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //получаем TextView
        tv_text=findViewById(R.id.tv_text);

    Helper helper = new Helper();
      helper.getLastId(new getResponse(){
            @Override
            void getJsonResponse(String id){

              //запуск в главном потоке
              HomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  tv_text.setText(...);
                }
              });
            }
    });
}}
}
```

Comment: _Третий вариант отдаёт ошибку_:

    'E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.example.apps, PID: 11183
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
............
        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:8908)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5730)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5571)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5528)'

Comment: Метод `getResponse().getJsonResponse(String id)` выполняется НЕ в основном потоке, так он вызывается в потоке запроса `okhttp`, и следовательно работать с элементами пользовательского интерфейса вы в этом методе не можете. Простой способ, использовать `Handler` или `Broadcast` для передачи сообщений

Comment: Поправил ответ. Запуск через runOnUiThread.